# Deshacer hover desde JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

tengo un elemento el cual cambia el pasar el cursor, esto con :hover

Quiero poder deshacer ese cambio desde javascript pero que siga funcionando el hover al volver a pasar el cursor.

```
.con_inf .inside:hover {
          width: 50%;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: white;
        }
```

Comment: coloca tu codigo porfavor

Comment: .con_inf : hover {
          width: 50%;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
          height: 100%;
        }

Comment: El efecto funciona bien, cuando saco el cursor el elemento vuelve a su estado normal, pero quiero que pueda volver a su estado normal desde codigo.

Comment: Formula mejor la pregunta. Me es dificil dar una respuesta con ese pequeño código y tu descripción. Eliminarlo desde el código trae muchas preguntas... quieres que se elimine mediante el código cuando el puntero pase por encima del elemento? o cuando el usuario realice que tipo de acción? Por favor suministra mas detalles así te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Mi duda es...¿A que te refieres con "deshacer ese cambio" pero a la vez siga funcionando el hover? ¿Quieres cambiar su funcionalidad pero haciendo que funcione como siempre?

Comment: Para que entiendan mejor: Al pasar el cursor se cambiar el ancho del DIV, y al sacar el cursor vuelve a su estado original. Dentro de este DIV tengo un botón y quiero que al pulsarlo, el DIV vuelva a su estado original. Ya lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

Le quité el hover del CSS y agregué una nueva clase

.con_inf .inside.abierto {
          width: 50%;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: white;
        }

Comment: Y desde JS interercepto el HOVER y le añado la clase 'abierto'. Y en el clic del botón le quito la clase 'abierto'

Comment: Tuve que resolverlo así pero quería ver si se podía hacer manteniendo el HOVER en CSS, y que desde el botón se removiera el HOVER activo.

Comment: Que bien que lo resolvieras, puedes cerrar la pregunta si quieres añadiendo y describiendo bien como lo solucionaste para que otras personas con el mismo objetivo se puedan guiar. Trata de poner un ejemplo práctico del porqué y para que lo necesitabas hacer, porque yo aún no entendí cual era el objetivo de tu post.

Comment: El código final me quedó de la siguiente manera:

CSS
     .con_inf .inside.abierto{
          width: 50%;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: white;
        }
Ahí simplemente le quité el 'hover'

Comment: Después capturo el 'hover' desde JS:

$( ".con_inf .inside" ).hover(
   function() {
 $( this ).addClass( "abierto" );
}, function() {
 $( this ).removeClass( "abierto" );
}
);